# Find a value in a list but not in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of 100 comma-separated numbers, I need to find which numbers are in the list but not in (select some_value from some_table) .... something like minus between 2 selects .... is there a direct way to do that.
I am using oracle 12g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string into a collection:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE numberlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_Number_List(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN numberlist DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       numberlist := numberlist();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start ) );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 ) );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( split_Number_List( '1,2,3,5,8,13,21' ) )
MINUS
SELECT id FROM your_table
```

**Query 2**:

or, you could use regular expressions:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( '1,2,3,5,8,13,21', '\d+', 1, LEVEL ) )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( '1,2,3,5,8,13,21', '\d+' )
MINUS
SELECT id FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `XMLTable()` to turn a string list of numbers into a

```
select to_number(x.column_value) from xmltable('1,3,5,7,9') x
where not exists (
  select some_value from some_table where some_value = to_number(x.column_value)
);
```

or if `some_value` isn't indexed a minus might be more effiecient:

```
select to_number(column_value) from xmltable('1,3,5,7,9')
minus
select some_value from some_table;
```

The string list is handled as an [XQuery expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5091), or more specifically an XQuery sequence:

> The comma (,) constructor creates sequences. Sequence-manipulating functions such as union and intersect are also available. All XQuery sequences are effectively flat: a nested sequence is treated as its flattened equivalent. Thus, for instance, (1, 2, (3, 4, (5), 6), 7) is treated as (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7). A singleton sequence, such as (42), acts the same in most XQuery contexts as does its single item, 42. Remember that the result of any XQuery expression is a sequence.

Quick demo:

```
with some_table(some_value) as (
  select 1 from dual
  union all select 7 from dual
)
select to_number(x.column_value) from xmltable('1,3,5,7,9') x
where not exists (
  select some_value from some_table where some_value = to_number(x.column_value)
);

              TO_NUMBER(X.COLUMN_VALUE)
---------------------------------------
                                      5
                                      3
                                      9
```